# When I reload the page the notes that I saved are not there anymore (react)

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useState, useEffect ,Date } from 'react'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const defaulttext = "Add a task...";
  const [inputtext, setinputtext] = useState(defaulttext)  
  const [note, setnote] = useState("")
  const [savedNotes, setSavedNotes] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    
    localStorage.setItem('sNotes',JSON.stringify(savedNotes))
    
  }, [savedNotes])
  useEffect(()=>{

    const saveNotesFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sNotes'));
    if(saveNotesFromStorage){
      setSavedNotes(saveNotesFromStorage)

    }

  },[savedNotes])
  

  const handlechange = (e)=>{

    setinputtext(e.target.value) 

  }
  const handlefocus = ()=>{
    if(inputtext === defaulttext){
      setinputtext('')
    }
  }


  const savenote = () => {
    const newNote = {
      id: uuidv4(), // Generate a unique id based on the current timestamp
      text: inputtext
      
    };
    console.log(uuidv4() )
    setSavedNotes([...savedNotes, newNote]); // Add the new note to the existing notes array
    setinputtext(defaulttext); // Reset input field to default text
  };
 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(note);
  }, [note]);
  return (
    <>
      <div className='containerr flex flex-col w-[35%] justify-center '>

        <div className="navbar bg-green-600 flex flex-row w-[100%] justify-between">
          <span>Todo List</span>
          
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" className="lucide lucide-menu"><line x1="4" x2="20" y1="12" y2="12" /><line x1="4" x2="20" y1="6" y2="6" /><line x1="4" x2="20" y1="18" y2="18" /></svg>
        
        </div>
        <div className='inputtext  justify-self-center ml-10 mt-4 mb-4 mr-10   flex flex-row '>

          <input onChange={handlechange} onFocus={handlefocus} type="text" value={inputtext} className=' bg-green-300 w-full outline-none ' />

          <svg  onClick={savenote} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="current" stroke="black" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" className="lucide lucide-plus bg-green-300 w-[23px]"><path d="M5 12h14" /><path d="M12 5v14" /></svg>

        </div>

      <div className='mynotes flex flex-col bg-green-500 min-h-[400px] text-center text-xl'> 
      <span className='bg-green-950  text-white p-3'>MyNotes</span>

      {savedNotes.length === 0 ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
      <div>
        {savedNotes.map((savednote)=>(
          <div  key = {savednote.id} className="note bg-green-200 mt-3 mb-3">{savednote.text}</div>
        ))}
      
      </div>
        )}
      </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

I want to store the note in localstorage but when i reload the page the notes dont persist

I tried using getitem and setitem and tried checking if the notes already exist and saving them to the localstorage I dont get why the data in localstorage wont persist .
I checked to see if setting the localstorage was even working and yes there were objects created in the local storage but when I reload the page the just disappear . I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that when the first `useEffect()` runs on mount it will set your local storage value to an empty array (as your `savedNotes` array is initially empty), which results in the previously persisted value being cleared out.

Instead, use the [`useState()` initializer function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters) to initiate your state to the value stored in local storage, or default it to an empty array if it doesn't exist:

```js
const [savedNotes, setSavedNotes] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sNotes')) || []);
```

When react mounts your component and creates the `savedNotes` state value, it will invoke the state initializer function once on the initial render, allowing you to grab your value from local storage.

Now you can remove the second `useEffect()` and update your local storage when `savedNotes` changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('sNotes',JSON.stringify(savedNotes))  
}, [savedNotes]);
```

Comment: thank you so much ! I tried doing everything but somehow missed the basic part .